# How do I handle input/ouput format in competitive programming sites like SPOJ?

Tags: c++, c

The solution format of most problems are
1) Input no of test cases
2) Give the 'test cases' number of input
3) output answer for each test case at once

```
Example  
3(Total test cases)  
12 3( test case 1)  
32 4( test case 2)  
65 1(test case 3)  

output:  
4(solution to test case1)  
3(sol to tc2)
8(sol to tc3)
```

Once I calculate the answer of each test case, do I need to store it somewhere until all test cases are over and then display the answer line by line?

If I am thinking correctly, I should be using arrays to store solution to each test case and then display the array at the end. The alternative solution, enter test case and print the solution is something I've got. but that doesn't seem to be accepted in online judge. How do I handle this in c/c++. In python it should be simple.

Comment: You don't need to store the result. Print them right away. `stdin` and `stdout` are separate streams

Comment: @EugeneSh. You should make that an answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Printing them right away is not accepted. The answer has to be printer after input of all test cases.

Comment: Please read the corresponding online judge sites guidelines, or ask on their provided forums. Most of them are using standard input outpout file descriptorst to communicate with your program provided, though we can't tell finally here.

Comment: @AbhishekKusnoor I don't believe you, sorry. I've completed a bunch of SPOJ challenges before, and this was never an issue.

Comment: I've never had an issue outputting each result as it is computed before reading the next test case.  If you're having trouble with a specific problem then you should ask about that rather than a general question like this.  It would let us see your code and give suggestions on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store the result. Print the result right away as it is computed. The `stdin` and `stdout` are separate streams which are not interfering with each other. The general structure of SPOJ program in `c` would be something like:

```
int main(void) {
    ....
    int tc;
    scanf("%d", &tc); // Read number of testcases
    for(i=0; i<tc; i++)
    {
        readInput(&input...);
        computeResult(input...., &output....);
        printResult(output....);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just needed to append a "\n" The format wasn't clear. Its so dumb of me to ask this question! :/